# Why can one ignore the real part of a complex number because of Fourier transform "only using the rotational part"?

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Why can one ignore the real part of a complex number because of Fourier transform "only using the rotational part"? Particularly, what property of Fourier transform is this?

Like given in this thread:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78638/why-do-we-use-s-j-omega-in-ac-analysis-instead-of-s-sigmaj-omega

---

Essentially they say that (quoting clabacchio):

> The reason why S=jω is chosen to evaluate AC signals is that it allows
>   to convert the Laplace transform into Fourier transform.
>
> The reason is that while S is a complex variable, what's used in the
>   Fourier representation is just the rotational (imaginary) component,
>   hence σ=0.

Comment: *Quoting the accepted answer by Kaz:* "What's happening is that $\sigma$ is being ignored because it is assumed to be zero. The reason for it is that we are looking at the response of the system to periodic (and thus non-decaying) sinusoidal signals, whereby Laplace conveniently reduces to Fourier along the imaginary axis. The real axis in the Laplace domain represents exponential decay/growth factors that pure signals do not have, and which Fourier does not model."

Comment: Physically $\omega$ encodes frequency of pure oscillation while $\sigma$ encodes dissipation. A common simplifying assumption in electronics is that the dissipation is negligible so you can deal with pure oscillation.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Okay but why exactly is the real axis in Laplace domain "exponential decay/growth" factors, because I'm not familiar with Laplace transform? Or perhaps it's a common property?

Comment: @mavavilj More or less what you are doing in both cases is writing a function as a "linear combination" of a continuum of exponentials with different coefficients. The  Laplace transform with a positive real part of $s$ corresponds to finding the coefficients of exponentials which are decaying (and oscillating) as you go forward in time. The Fourier transform with real $\omega$ corresponds to exponentials with no real part, which are purely oscillating.

Comment: @Ian I see (by looking at the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Formal_definition), and why does Fourier transform ignore those?

Comment: The Fourier transform ignores dissipation because that's how it's defined. Why you would use the Fourier transform vs. the Laplace transform depends on the problem in front of you. In the context of electronics it makes sense because dissipation may take minutes while an oscillation of the circuit may take 1/60 of a second or less.

Comment: @Ian I don't see how it's defined that way? The FT looks like the Laplace, but it also has a negative part rather than being $\int_0^{\infty}$ and it has some more parameters on the exponential.

Comment: The Fourier transform is a two-sided version of the Laplace transform (which makes sense because pure oscillation can extend in both directions in time, whereas exponential decay turns into exponential growth as you go backward in time) with an extra factor of $j$ thrown in so that pure oscillations correspond to real values of the parameter. The $\pi$'s and such are convention-dependent and are not conceptually important.

Comment: @Ian What do you mean "pure oscillation" and "real values of the parameter" (what parameter)? Why does this lead to that "pure oscillations correspond to real values of the parameter"?

Comment: You define the Fourier transform as a function of the parameter $\omega$, the exponential $e^{j\omega}$ is purely oscillatory when $\omega$ is real. If you stripped out the factor of $j$ in the definition of the Fourier transform, then pure oscillations would be on the imaginary axis of the $\omega$ plane instead.

Comment: @Ian I still don't understand what you mean by pure oscillation.